# Amazon RDS have different global values on similar host

Tags: mysql, rds

I have 2 database on two different RDS hosts using a similar group. Most of the mysql global variables are same except for binlog_format and log_bin. As these are not configured within parameter groups, I am not sure why they are different for different database host.
Mysql version is 5.5

```
Mysql Property  host1  host2
--------------  -----  ---------
binlog_format   MIXED  STATEMENT
log_bin         ON     OFF
```

Kindly guide where to look for.
Thanks